# Overloaded function in derived class with Polymorphism (C++)

Tags: c++, class, polymorphism, overloading, virtual

Considering this code example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base
{
private:
    int number;

public:
    Base():number(10){}
    ~Base(){}
    virtual void print()
    {
        cout << "Base class" << endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived():Base(){}
    ~Derived(){}
    void print(int value)
    {
        //printing number in Base class and paramter value
        cout << "Derived with value " << value << " number is" << number << endl; 
    }
};
```

I wanted to use polymorphism and call theoverloaded  `print()` function.
So use these classes as follows:

```
void somewhere_else()
{
    Base* polymorphism = new Derived();
    polymorphism->print(5); //Error indicating there are too many parameter
                            //thinking that I am trying to use print in Base class
    ((Derived*)polymorphism)->print(5) 
                       //This works as I am casting the variable as Derived variable
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't call print() from the base class pointer (compilation error, see comment above).  I can only call it with a cast. 
Is there a better way to keep the polymorphism and still calls overloaded function based on derived class?

Comment: `void Derived::print(int value)` doesn't override `Base::print`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Why is that? Is it because I am missing `override`?

Comment: in `Base`: `void print()`. In `Derived`: `void print(int value)` different signatures. Slapping an `override` tag on it would help catch the error and totally be worth your time.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have two different member functions, that have different signatures:

- a virtual `print()` that takes no argument.  It is declared and defined in `Base`, and inherited in `Derived`
- a non-virtual `print()` that takes one `int` argument.  It is declared and defined ONLY for `Derived`

So the base object doesn't know a print function with an int parameter.  This is why you need to cast (which is by the way a symptom that should ring alarm bells if you need it).

**How to improve ?**

First, if you want to **override** a virtual function in a derived class, use the keyword `override`:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived():Base(){}
    ~Derived(){}
    void print(int value) override
    {
        ...
    }
};
```

This will ensure an error message in case of subtle mismatch in the function signature:

```
prog.cpp:23:10: error: ‘void Derived::print(int)’ marked ‘override’, but does not override
     void print(int value) override
          ^~~~~
```

Then make sure that the signatures are aligned in the base class and derived class (i.e. either both take an int argument or non of them.

Note that you can't access a `private` member of the base class in a derived class.  You have to define `number` as `protected` to print it in `Derived`.

Finally, if you have a base class having a virtual member, it is a sound practice to systematically make the destructor virtual.  This will avoid subtle bugs for more complex classes:

```
class Base
{
protected:
    int number;   
public:
    Base():number(10){}
    virtual ~Base(){}
    virtual void print(int value)
    {
        ...
    }
};
```

Here the [online demo](https://ideone.com/lWf9TS)

Now that the things are working, here a short article making the [difference between **overload** and **override**](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/function-overloading-vs-function-overriding-in-cpp/).